# Multiple sources for Gulp task

Tags: gulp

I am trying to accomplish a few tasks that I feel like should be relatively basic but I am having a really hard time figuring what I am doing wrong.

I need to:

1. lint javascript that I have written,
2. concat javascript that I have written with 3rd party javascript downloaded via NPM,
3. uglify it

I store paths in my package.json file, so I have this for my app libraries:

```
{
  ...,
  "paths": {
    "src": {
      "js": "./src/js/",
      "appLibraries": [
        "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
        "./node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.js"
    },
    "dist": {
      "js": "./build/js"
    }
  }
}
```

I have a simple jshint function:

```
function lintScripts() {
    return gulp
        .src( pkg.paths.src.js + '**/*.js' )
        .pipe( $.jshint() )
        .pipe( $.jshint.reporter( 'jshint-stylish' )
}
```

This works fine. My function to actually compile my JS:

```
function scripts() {
    lintScripts();

    return gulp
    .src( pkg.paths.src.js + '**/*.js', pkg.paths.src.appLibraries )
    // do my other stuff
    .pipe( gulp.dest( pkg.paths.dist.js )
}
```

When I do this, I only get the first argument actually processed. I've tried swapping the `src` line for this: `.src([ pkg.paths.src.js + '**/*.js', pkg.paths.src.appLibraries ])` since I know it can accept an array, but apparently it can't accept an array of arrays because I get this error: `Invalid glob argument after ./src/js/**/*.js`

I can get around this by updated my package.json paths to the following, but this seems silly and redundant:

```
{
  ...,
  "paths": {
    "src": {
      "js": "./src/js/",
      "appLibraries": [
        "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
        "./node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.js",
        "./src/js/**/*.js"
    },
    "dist": {
      "js": "./build/js"
    }
  }
}
```

What am I missing???

Answer (score 0):

Besides a couple of typos in the code you presented, it does work for me if I put the array ( `pkg.paths.src.appLibraries`) first and spreading that array and puuting the whole thing in an array as in:

`.src( [...pkg.paths.src.appLibraries, pkg.paths.src.js + '**/*.js'] )`

don't ask me why these changes makes a difference - I looked through `gulpjs` issues and `src` documentation and couldn't find anything that indicated it should be necessary.  I would recommend filing an issue there yourself but it may sit awhile.

Perhaps `gulp.src` can take an array **or** a string but not both.  The documentation could be more formal on this point...

You can always add a `src` later like this:

```js
function scripts() {

  return gulp

  .src(pkg.paths.src.js + '**/*.js')
    .pipe(gulp.src(pkg.paths.src.appLibraries))
    .pipe( gulp.dest( pkg.paths.dist.js ))
};
```

Comment: It will compile just fine this way, but in only compiles the ````pkg.paths.src.appLibraries```` destination and leaves the remaining custom code untouched. Its really strange to me.

Comment: Sorry, you are right.  But I modified my answer to something which does work - at least in your simple task.  I originally thought the array spreading would work, but it doesn't if the array is second and if the whole `src` is not wrapped in the array.

Comment: Still not working, but I found a workaround and am posting as the answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Both methods I showed work.  The code you showed has typos - did you ever fix them?

Answer (score 0):

I never solved this the "right" way, but what I did for anyone having the same issue is I made a variable to grab the array from my package.json, then pushed my new string to the end of it.